# Thermodynamic explanation for working of refrigerator

Tags: thermodynamics

What are the list of processes involved in the working of refrigerator (such that they result in continuous refrigeration) ?(like isothermal compression.....)(like processes in Carnot cycle)....
**Note**: can I get a High school level explanation if possible...

Comment: [Heat flow to hotter regions](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/thermo/refrig.html).

Comment: @Farcher are there no named sequencial steps as in Carnot cycle

Comment: But it is the Carnot cycle reversed , absorbing instead of providing work.

Comment: Yeah but when I tried to understand how refrigerator works....I couldn’t match the process (which are reversed to carnot’s ) with the real working procedure

Comment: Adiabatic compression in the compressor; heat transfer to the environment at the condenser; adiabatic flashing across the expansion valve; heat transfer to the refrigerant at the evaporator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The diagram below is for a Carnot heat engine cycle. If the cycle is reversed, it becomes a  Carnot vapor-compression refrigeration cycle. In other words,

1-2 is instead 2-1 and becomes a reversible adiabatic expansion (Turbine)

2-3 is instead 3-2 and becomes a reversible isothermal compression (Condenser- Heat out into the high temperature environment- i.e., the room in which the refrigerator is located)

3-4 is instead 4-3 and becomes a reversible adiabatic compression (the compressor)

4-1 is instead 1-4 and becomes a reversible isothermal expansion (Evaporator- heat out of the low temperature environment- i.e. the environment to be cooled)

Although it is the most efficient cycle, the Carnot cycle is not practical because it requires the compressor to compress two phases (liquid and vapor) and requires expansion of two phases in the turbine. The practical refrigeration cycle is the ideal vapor compression cycle that vaporizes the refrigerant completely before being compressed and replaces the turbine with a throttle valve.

Hope this helps.

[image]

Comment: Yeah this is what I was expecting.:-)

Comment: Then the answer is acceptable?

Comment: Yeah totally !thnx